FastAPI 422 Unprocessable Entity Error for having upload file and parameters in body
I have an API which works when it is like this:
@router.put('/edit_teacher', status_code=200, response_model=TeacherDisplay)
async def edit_teacher(teacher_id: int, db: DB_DEPENDENCY, teacher_new_name: str | None = None, teacher_pic: UploadFile | None = None):
    return await teacher_functions.edit_teacher(teacher_id=teacher_id, teacher_new_name=teacher_new_name, db=db, teacher_pic=teacher_pic)

but I want to get teacher_id and teacher_new_name in body but whatever I do I get 422 Unprocessable Entity Error
I searched a lot and it seems it has something to do with sending file next to those parameters but I have a similar API like this:
@router.post('/add_teacher', status_code=200, response_model=TeacherDisplay)
async def add_teacher(teacher_name: TEACHER_NAME_BODY, db: DB_DEPENDENCY, teacher_pic: UploadFile | None = None):
    return await teacher_functions.add_teacher(teacher_name=teacher_name, db=db, teacher_pic=teacher_pic)


I don't understand why this works fine but the other one doesn't. the main problem is that I want to send teacher_id and teacher_new_name as body parameters and teacher_new_name should be optional.
I have tried many different ways. first I was writing it like this:
class EditTeacherModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    teacher_new_name: str | None = None

@router.put('/edit_teacher', status_code=200, response_model=TeacherDisplay)
async def edit_teacher(request: EditTeacherModel, db: DB_DEPENDENCY, teacher_pic: UploadFile | None = None):
    return await teacher_functions.edit_teacher(request=request, db=db, teacher_pic=teacher_pic)

even:
@router.put('/edit_teacher', status_code=200, response_model=TeacherDisplay)
async def edit_teacher(request: EditTeacherModel, db: DB_DEPENDENCY, teacher_pic: UploadFile | None = None):
    teacher_id = request.id
    teacher_new_name = request.teacher_new_name
    return await teacher_functions.edit_teacher(teacher_id=teacher_id, teacher_new_name=teacher_new_name, db=db, teacher_pic=teacher_pic)

didn't work.

File upload requires for the request body to be encoded in multipart/form-data (as this format can contain files) format instead of JSON, but any Pydantic models will be interpreted as JSON-formatted body content.
To send any additional data together with file, you can either encode the file in base64 to be sent inside the JSON body, or use simple form data fields next to a regular file upload, as described here
